# Prove or disprove that $ f(x) < q|x|+p$ if and only if $f(x)$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I need to prove that if $f$ is uniformly continuous then there exist $q,p > 0$ s.t $f(x) \le q|x|+p$.
Then I need to prove or disprove that if $f(x) \le q|x|+p$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

I am a bit lost. From where should I start? Should I define $f(x)= qx + p$ ?

Comment: Take $f$ as the dirichlet function, $q=1, p=2$.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD : $f$ is arbitrary here.

Comment: @CarlHeckman there's an if and an only if part.

Comment: Based on your other question, just a clarification. @CarlHeckman answer bellows shows that if $f$ is uniformly continuous then there exists $q,p$ which satisfy your condition. On the other hand YoTengoUnLCD example shows that existence of such $p,q$ is not enough to $f$ be uniformly continuous.

Comment: @iiivooo what is YoTengoUnLCD example?

Comment: @iiivooo didn't we proved that f(k) < k doesnt mean f(x)<x ?

Comment: @AliAmmar read the first comment, YoTengoUnLCD  suggested to use  [Dirichlet function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html) as a contradiction.

Comment: @iiivooo and what about the f(k)? how to build up to f(x)?

Comment: Sorry don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch of proof of second question:

(1) Uniform continuity means that there is a $\delta$ such that $\big| f(x)-f(y) \big| < 1$ when $\big|x -y \big| < \delta$.

(2) Hence, $\displaystyle\left| f\left(k\delta \over2\right) - f\left((k-1)\delta \over 2\right)\right| < 1$, for all integers $k$. (Why?)

(3) $\displaystyle\left| f(\delta) - f(0) \right| \le \left| f(\delta) - f\left(\delta\over2\right) \right| + \left| f\left(\delta\over2\right) - f(0) \right| \le 1+1 =2 $. Now show that $\displaystyle\left| f\left(k\delta\over2\right) - f(0) \right|\le k$. (Why?)

(4) Handle numbers which are not an integral multiple of $\displaystyle{\delta\over 2}$ in a similar fashion.

Comment: why is number 2 true?

Comment: What is $\displaystyle\left| {k\delta \over 2} - {(k-1)\delta \over 2}\right|$?

Comment: to what question are you answer? I see nothing related to q|x|+p

Comment: It builds up to it. Once you show that $\displaystyle\left| f\left(x\delta \over 2\right)-f(0)\right| \le |x|$, then you know that $$f\left({x\delta \over 2}\right) \le |x| + f(0),$$ and now you can replace $\displaystyle{x\delta \over 2}$ with $x$.

Comment: $x$ belongs to $\mathbb R$ but $k$ is an integer so I can't just replace $k$ with $x$

Comment: That's where step (4) comes in.