# if $|f(k) | \le k$ for all integers $k$, does that mean $ |f(x)| \le |x|$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

> if $|f(k) | \le k$ for all integers $k$, does that mean $ |f(x)| \le |x|$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb R$?

Note that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

This question is a follow up to a previous answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1716695/326454 so this answer is wrong write?

Comment: sorry i should say less or equal

Comment: You took out the 2 in the question and the $f(0)$. Did you mean to? That changed the question lots and makes @Dominik's answer invalid. Might be better as a new question as its drastically changed.

Comment: @Rise I just did, sorry

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1716695/326454 so this answer is wrong write?

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. Simply choose the function
$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x = \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & \text{else}\end{cases}$.

Comment: oh I should note that f is uniformly continuous

Comment: This counterexample still does the trick if you just make it uniformly continous, by taking the graph to be constant on $[0,1/3]$ a straight line to 1 between $[1/3,1/2]$ and again a straight line to zero between $[1/2,2/3]$ and then again constant on $[2/3,1]$ this is unformly continous since the function factorizes trough a compact space.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1716695/326454 so this answer is wrong write?

Comment: @AliAmmar No, that answer is correct. Note that the inequality depends on the $\delta$ that comes from the uniform continuity.

Comment: how to go from f(k$\delta$) < k to f(x) < x ?

Comment: You can't, as this would also be a false claim. Note that the other problem has some parameters $p$ and $q$. Please open another question if you want to discuss that answer. It is a completely different question from the one you've stated in your original post.

Answer (score 1):

Consider function $f(x)=\sin(x\pi)$. Then $f(k)=0$ for any $k\in \mathbb Z$ but $f(\frac{1}{2})=1$.

Comment: @AlexS sure, thank you!, I just noticed that as I hit save button.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1716695/326454 so this answer is wrong write?

Comment: Why it should be wrong?

Comment: @AliAmmar Using the notation of your second question, my solution satisfies your condition with $q=p=1$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean $|f(x)|\leq |k|$. If so, confider $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 2x & |x|\leq 1/2\\ 1 & x>1/2\\ -1 & x<-1/2.\end{cases}$$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1716695/326454 so this answer is wrong write?

Comment: He should have replaced $k$ with $|k|$ in part 3, but otherwise looks good.

Comment: but we just proved f(k)<k doesn't mean f(x) < x

Comment: The link you provided never claims that  $f (k)\leq |k|$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(x)=\alpha\sin(\pi x)$ for any large fixed $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, $|f(k)|=\alpha\sin (\pi k)=0\leq |k|$ for any integer, but $|f(\frac{2t}{2})|=\alpha>2t$ for any $t<\frac{\alpha}{2}$.